# Values on bar plots and labels

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFug7.jpg)Im a beginner in programming with Python and I need your help!

Im trying to put the value of the bars on top or above them depending on their position on the y-axis. In the plus side of the y-axis I want to put the values above the bars and in the minus side, I want to out the values under the bars.

Im also trying to put the labels of the bars on top of the graph in the same color as the bars.

NEW:

ax.1+plt.bar(r, elements,color=bar_colors,edgecolor='none',width=bardWidth)
ax=dataset.plot(width=5.0,kind='bar',y=dataset.columns,figsize=(6,5),zorder=3)

for p in ax.patches:
ax.annotate("%.2f"%p.get.height(),(p.get_x()+p.get.width()/2.,p.get_height()),ha='center',va='center',xytext=(0,10),textcoords='offsetpoints')

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this. If yes then try to use `ax.patches` to put value on the bar graph.

**df:**

```
    a   b   c   d
0   66  92  98  17
1  -83  57  86  97
2   96  47 -73  32
```

---

```
ax = df.plot(width=0.8, kind='bar',y=df.columns,figsize=(10,5))
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(round(p.get_height(),2)), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.01),color='black')
  
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
```

---

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your help so far! I tried it but unfortunately, not all numbers are shown on the graph and they are not positioned properly. Do you know how this could happen?

Comment: ax = dataset.plot(width=0.8, kind='bar',y=dataset.columns,figsize=(10,5))
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(round(p.get_height(),2)), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.01),color='black')

Comment: `1.005` and `1.01` adjust them as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it! :) and do you know how to fix the problem that not all values are shown above or below the bars?

Comment: Can you update your question and paste the screenshot?

Comment: I now added a new code. It partly worked. However, the values are all above the bars. But I want to put the negative one below the bars. But I don't know how. Can you help here?

Comment: Show screenshot please

Comment: I added the picture in my description above. In the beginning it says "enter image description here'. Click on it and you will see the screenshot. Thank you :)

Comment: Check p.get_height() it should have negative value. Debug on it.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: print(p.get_height()) #<------ just print and see. Coz logically you are giving coordinates to put text. So it should have negative y coordinate

Comment: No I m just telling you to check what values you are getting.

Comment: Use this only: `ax.annotate("%.2f"%p.get_height(),(p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.01),ha='center',va='center')`  remove `xytext=(0,10),textcoords='offsetpoints'`

Comment: The code doesnt change anything but putting the numbers into chaotic positions. However, I noticed that the number are all positive eventhough some should be negative cause the bar plots are negative. Do you know where the mistake is here?

Comment: Are you adding something to the coordinate: `ax.1+plt.bar` ???

Comment: I put this: ax1 = plt.bar(r, elements, color=bar_colors,edgecolor="none", width=barWidth)

Comment: and also this: ax = dataset.plot(width=5.0, kind='bar',y=dataset.columns,figsize=(10,7),zorder=3)

Comment: it seems something is getting added up. `print(p.get_x(), p.get_height())`

Comment: If I write this, nothing changes again :/

Comment: -_- I am telling you to check the value. It won't change anything obviously